# ProgressDialog in TabHost application ofandroid

Tags: android, android-tabhost, progressdialog

I want to use the Progress Dailog in my application. I am facing one issue in doing it, after some RnD I came to know that it is not quite possible to create the progress Dialog I have the Activity Group Class for the TabHost in the application.

I have exactly the same scenario, I have the TabHost in my application and an ActivityGroup Class that has the TabHost Classes. So, when I try to create the Progress Dialog for the Class that is in the Activity Group Class I cannot create it. But if I try to create the Progress Dialog for the Class that is not in the Activity Group I can create it with no issues.

Is there any solutions now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with context of the progress dialog

Try giving the context of the dialog as getParent()

ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), " Loading...", "Please wait...", true, false);