# ProgressDialog in Tabhost Not Working

Tags: android, android-tabhost, progressdialog

i use three progress dialog in my activity

1. OnCreate()
2. When navigating to next page
3. When navigating to previous page

but after first time when I click next page button the application crashes with error `WINDOW LEAKED`

Here is my code kindly someone please tell what i am doing wrong

```
public class Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity_REQUESTS extends Activity implements  OnClickListener{

    String webrss, totalMovies;
    ProgressDialog dialog; 

    ListView RequestedMoviesListView;
    RequestMoviesCustomAdapter moviesCustomAdapter;
    ArrayList<RequestMovieListModel> adapters = new ArrayList<RequestMovieListModel>();

    LinearLayout requests_lineraLayout;

    Button first_page_button1_request, next_page_button1_request;

    TextView requests_textViewPages;
    int t,set=1;//for navigation purposes
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int tab=1, b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.request_list_layout_requests);


        RequestedMoviesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.requests_listView);
        RequestedMoviesListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        requests_lineraLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.request_linearLayout1);


        first_page_button1_request = (Button)findViewById(R.id.first_page_button1_request);
        next_page_button1_request = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_page_button1_request);
        first_page_button1_request.setOnClickListener(this);
        next_page_button1_request.setOnClickListener(this);

        requests_textViewPages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.requests_textViewPages);

        webrss = getString( R.string.requested_movies);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), webrss, 1).show();
        adapters.clear();
        moviesCustomAdapter = new RequestMoviesCustomAdapter(Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity_REQUESTS.this, R.layout.show_categories_list, adapters);
        moviesCustomAdapter.clear();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                MovieRequests();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        if(dialog.isShowing()){         
                            RequestedMoviesListView.setAdapter( moviesCustomAdapter );
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            MovieCount();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private void MovieCount() {
        try {
            URL yify = new URL(webrss);
            URLConnection tc = yify.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
                totalMovies = jsonObject.getString("MovieCount");
                int a = Integer.parseInt(totalMovies);
                t = (a/15)+1;

                requests_lineraLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (set == 1) {
                    requests_textViewPages.setText("1 of "+Integer.toString(t));
                }
                else{
                    requests_textViewPages.setText(set+" of "+Integer.toString(t));
                }

            }
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void MovieRequests() {
        try {   
            URL yify = new URL(webrss+"&set="+set);
            URLConnection tc = yify.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("RequestList"));

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    if (jo.has("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jo.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        String request_id = jo.getString("RequestID");
                        String m_title = jo.getString("MovieTitle");
                        String imdb_url = jo.getString("ImdbLink");
                        String m_cover = jo.getString("CoverImage");
                        String short_description = jo.getString("ShortDescription");

                        String genere = jo.getString("Genre");
                        String imdb_rating = jo.getString("MovieRating");
                        String date_added = jo.getString("DateAdded");

                        String votes = jo.getString("Votes");
                        String requester_user_id = jo.getString("UserID");
                        String requester_user_name = jo.getString("Username");


                        RequestMovieListModel request_movies = new RequestMovieListModel(request_id, m_title, imdb_url, m_cover, short_description
                                ,genere, imdb_rating, date_added, votes, requester_user_id, requester_user_name);
                        // Process a newly found station
                        moviesCustomAdapter.add(request_movies);                        
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.first_page_button1_request:
            if (set ==1) {
                moviesCustomAdapter.clear();
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        MovieRequests();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                if(dialog.isShowing()){         
                                    RequestedMoviesListView.setAdapter( moviesCustomAdapter );
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    MovieCount();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
            else{
                set = set-1;
                moviesCustomAdapter.clear();
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        MovieRequests();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                if(dialog.isShowing()){         
                                    RequestedMoviesListView.setAdapter( moviesCustomAdapter );
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    MovieCount();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.next_page_button1_request:
            set = set+1;
            moviesCustomAdapter.clear();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    MovieRequests();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            if(dialog.isShowing()){         
                                RequestedMoviesListView.setAdapter( moviesCustomAdapter );
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                MovieCount();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            thread1.start();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174): Activity androlizer.yify.torrent.Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2bec3268 that was originally added here
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity androlizer.yify.torrent.Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2bec3268 that was originally added here
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at androlizer.yify.torrent.Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity_REQUESTS.onClick(Request_Movies_Conatiner_Activity_REQUESTS.java:239)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 18:59:37.319: ERROR/WindowManager(14174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ProgressDialog in TabHost application ofandroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756081/progressdialog-in-tabhost-application-ofandroid)

Comment: Are you getting any other errors or messages in the logcat? Don't filter the logcat as you may miss something important. Post the relevant contents of the logcat in your question.

Comment: @David i have have added the error logCAT

Comment: @David Wasser  i have different case now check this out please

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace from logcat that is relevant to this error. That is the most important tool we have to identify the problem, so you need to provide that.

Comment: @David Wasser can u please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347277/android-display-threaded-comments-json

Answer (score 0):

Your are not dismissing the Dialog in the Second Tabas you have done in first tab just before MovieCount().

**EDIT:**

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                MovieRequests();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        if(dialog.isShowing()){         
                            ConfirmedMoviesListView.setAdapter( moviesCustomAdapter );                  dialog.dismiss();
                            MovieCount();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        }
    }
```

See this part...you are not dismissing it here... That was where I mentioned that you have to dismiss.

Comment: i'm dismissing it, only not stated here.it is giving a stack trace `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  progressdialog` i have done so much research but can't fing right solution for it.